# Blank page after submitting form

Tags: php, html

I don't know what is going on but I get blank page after submit form. File is responsible for integration my website with Mailchimp. Below I also share also html code. I looked at the variables and theoretically everything is correct in the php and html file. The API key is correct and so is the mailing list number from MailChimp. What could be causing this situation?

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) === false) {
        //Mailchimp API credentials
        $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $listID = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

        //Mailchimp API URL 
        $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . 'api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists?fields=' . $listID . '/members' . $memberID;

        // member information

        $json = json_encode ([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status' => 'subscribed',
        ]);

         // send a HTTP POST request with curl
         $ch = curl_init($url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         curl_close($ch);
         
         // store the status message based on response code
         if ($httpCode == 200) {
             $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #34A853">You have successfully subscribed to CodexWorld.</p>';
         } else {
             switch ($httpCode) {
                 case 214:
                     $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                     break;
                 default:
                     $msg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                     break;
             }
             $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">'.$msg.'</p>';
         }
     }else{
         $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
     }
 }
 // redirect to homepage
 header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```

```
<!-- Modal Newsletter Start-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-newsletter">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <?php echo $statusMsg: ?>
            <form method="post" action="action.php">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span>&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <h4>Subscribe to our newsletter</h4>
                    <p>Signup to our weekly newsletters to get the latest news, updates and amazing offers!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="emapleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter your email..." required>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Subscribe">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where in the `action.php` script do things fall over? Have you added debug statements to that script to see what you get?

Comment: You know that the PHP above has 2 extra closing curly braces at the end?

Comment: Check the server error log. Blank screen typical means error, which is not displayed by default.  At the command line, you could run `php -l action.php` to see if any syntax errors are reported. (looks like the file has some stray `}` at the end of the file?

Comment: I corrected the code. It still does not work. When I try to submit the form I get 500 Internal Server Error. This is information from the browser console.

Comment: So, as previously mentioned, check the `server error log` for more detail, the browser only knows the HTTP response code (the 500), and nothing else. You could also add (before the `session_start`, as a temporary check) `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` then try again.

Comment: I have something like this 'PHP Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL) in action.php on line 5'

Comment: Try changing `!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) === false`, to: `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false`  The extra `)` was part of the trouble, but then the leading `!` doesn't make sense against a second false check.

Comment: Problem resolved. Thank you guys!